# Error when trying to update_index with an ElasticSearch backend

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, wagtail

I have a Django environment set up to use ElasticSearch as the backend for our CMS, which is in Wagtail. I installed a recent version of ES (5.6.5 according to the service when I CURL it), and have my settings file using 'wagtail.wagtailsearch.backends.elasticsearch5' as the 'BACKEND' for WAGTAILSEARCH_BACKENDS. Wagtail is on version 1.13.1 according to my pip freeze, and the elasticsearch Python package is at 5.5.2. This all seems right per my reading of http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/search/backends.html.

The problem I am having is that when I try to do a './manage.py update_index', it gives me the following error:

```
$ ./manage.py update_index 
Updating backend: default
default: Rebuilding index wagtail__wagtailcore_page
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/management/commands/update_index.py", line 120, in handle
    self.update_backend(backend_name, schema_only=options.get('schema_only', False))
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/management/commands/update_index.py", line 77, in update_backend
    index.add_model(model)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch2.py", line 113, in add_model
    index=self.name, doc_type=mapping.get_document_type(), body=mapping.get_mapping(),
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py", line 137, in get_mapping
    self.get_field_mapping(field) for field in self.model.get_search_fields()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py", line 137, in <genexpr>
    self.get_field_mapping(field) for field in self.model.get_search_fields()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch.py", line 119, in get_field_mapping
    return self.get_field_column_name(field), mapping
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/backends/elasticsearch2.py", line 56, in get_field_column_name
    return prefix + field.get_attname(self.model)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/wrds/lib/python3.5/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailsearch/index.py", line 178, in get_attname
    return field.attname
AttributeError: 'ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'attname'
```

As I mentioned, the ES service is running and gives the expected reply to a CURL. I'm at a loss here as to how to resolve this error. Googling around for the error hasn't helped much: [this link](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24936?cversion=0&cnum_hist=1) seems to suggest that the problem may be a use of 'defer/only for a field in a model that has the reverse relationship explicitly removed', but I've searched our code, and am pretty sure we don't have anything using `only()` or `defer()` at all, let alone on a table/field that has had the reverse relationship removed. Any help is of course much appreciated!

Comment: To narrow down the problem, I'd suggest commenting out entries in your models' `search_fields` declarations until you find one that allows `update_index` to succeed. It seems surprising that this is apparently failing on the basic `wagtailcore_page` model rather than a specific page type within your project, but perhaps things will become clearer once you've found a specific field that's causing the problem...

Comment: @gasman Excellent idea, I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: @gasman Well, I tried commenting out each occurrence of 'search_fields' individually, and got the same error each time. I also tried commenting them all out at once, and still got that error. I am trying to think if this is because of something else we are doing... We have another app in our project with a lot of models where we do not let Django manage the model (in the class Meta we set `managed = false`). Could that be causing issues?

Answer (score 1):

I found the trouble. The issue wasn't in our project's code, but in a `search_fields` for the GridIndexPage class in wagtailgridder (v. 0.9.18). I know the developer for wagtailgridder, and he is going to make the necessary changes there. Thanks for the assist, @gasman! Your suggestion lead me to the right place.